# Where can I obtain an exhaustive list of Google's Schema.org type values?

Tags: schema.org, actions-on-google

Google's [Query Patterns](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/QueryPatterns) documentation refers to use of Schema.org types, but I cannot find a way to obtain the comprehensive list of values that can be returned for enumerated types such as $SchemaOrg_Color, $SchemaOrg_servesCusine and $SchemaOrg_Product. I've checked the schema.org website and still cannot find values, only types. I've also checked schema.org's github project (of course, Google's values are likely different).

Comment: Did you consider looking at http://schema.org/?

Comment: Yes, that's the first place I looked. Couldn't find any values there, just types.

Comment: For those voting off topic - how is trying to get the possible values for a set of types that are used in coding off topic? The question seems perfectly valid and legitimate and the documentation (about programming for the Assistant) fails to provide the information needed.